# Sql server errors in query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am trying to collaborate 3 queries to perform arithmetic operation. The queries are shown in

```
(SELECT ITEM_ID,ISNULL(SUM(REC_GOOD_QTY),0)
FROM INVENTORY_ITEM
WHERE COMPANY_ID = 1
AND INVENTORY_ITEM.COMPANY_BRANCH_ID = 1
AND INVENTORY_ITEM.INV_ITEM_STATUS = 'Inward'
AND GRN_DATE <  CAST('2017-01-10 00:00:00.0' AS DATETIME)
GROUP BY INVENTORY_ITEM.ITEM_ID) - 
(SELECT ITEM_ID, SUM ( TOTAL_LITRE )
FROM STOCK_REQUISITION_ITEM B, STOCK_REQUISITION A 
WHERE A.ID = B.REQUISITION_ID
AND A.COMPANY_ID = 1
AND A.REQ_FROM_BRANCH_ID = 1 
AND A.REQUISITION_DATE < CAST('2017-01-10 00:00:00.0' AS DATETIME)
GROUP BY B.ITEM_ID) + 
(SELECT ITEM_ID, SUM ( RETURN_QUANTITY )
FROM STOCK_RETURN_ITEM B, STOCK_RETURN A 
WHERE A.ID = B.STOCK_RETURN_ID
AND A.COMPANY_ID = 1
AND A.COMPANY_BRANCH_ID = 1 
AND A.RETURN_DATE <= CAST('2017-01-10 00:00:00.0' AS DATETIME)
GROUP BY B.ITEM_ID)
```

I am getting this error.

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'.
>   42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '+'

Comment: This query is a mess from a formatting perspective. Do yourself a favor and get familiar with white space. You also should use sensible table aliases. An alias is not very useful if you have to reference the main part of the query over and over to see what table A.SomeColumn comes from. Then you are inconsistent with using them. Sometimes you do and others you don't. Last but not least is the antiquated join syntax. The ANSI-92 style joins have been around for over 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Exists a table where you have a list of ITEM_ID not repeated? Inventory_item table has more than one row for the same ITEM_ID, right?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely correct bro. Actually your solution is much closer but returns the sum value incorrect :(

Answer (score 0):

In your queries you always returns two fields ITEM_ID and a numeric field.

To apply an arithmetical operation you must return one numeric field

The first query:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID,ISNULL(SUM(REC_GOOD_QTY),0)
```

becomes

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(REC_GOOD_QTY),0)
```

The second query:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, SUM ( TOTAL_LITRE )
```

becomes

```
SELECT SUM ( TOTAL_LITRE )
```

The third query:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, SUM ( RETURN_QUANTITY )
```

becomes

```
SELECT SUM ( RETURN_QUANTITY )
```

So the `GROUP BY` returns more than one row per query

**UPDATE**

i try to rewrite your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ii.item_id, 
ISNULL(
    (SELECT SUM(ii2.rec_good_qty)
    FROM inventory_item ii2
    WHERE ii2.item_id = ii.item_id
    AND ii.company_id = 1
    AND ii.company_branch_id = 1
    AND ii.inv_item_status = 'Inward'
    AND ii.grn_date <  CAST('2017-01-10 00:00:00.0' AS DATETIME))
    ,0) -
ISNULL(
    (SELECT SUM(total_litre)
    FROM stock_requisition_item b
    JOIN stock_requisition a
        ON a.id = b.requisition_id
    WHERE a.company_id = 1
    AND a.req_from_branch_id = 1 
    AND a.requisition_date < CAST('2017-01-10 00:00:00.0' AS DATETIME))
,0) +
ISNULL(
    (SELECT SUM(return_quantity)
    FROM stock_return_item b
    JOIN stock_return a
        ON a.id = b.stock_return_id
    WHERE a.company_id = 1
    AND a.company_branch_id = 1
    AND a.return_date <= CAST('2017-01-10 00:00:00.0' AS DATETIME))
,0) AS result
FROM inventory_item ii
WHERE ii.company_id = 1
AND ii.company_branch_id = 1
AND ii.inv_item_status = 'Inward'
AND ii.grn_date <  CAST('2017-01-10 00:00:00.0' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Thank you for response sir. Can You rewrite the query for me?

Comment: Sir, but ITEM_ID also want to printed in my result how to do that with these queries

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on here for details. And we aren't actually sure if you are using mysql or sql server but pretty sure you are using sql server. I think you can accomplish what you are trying to do with something along these lines.

```
with Iventory as
(
    SELECT i.ITEM_ID
        , GoodQty = ISNULL(SUM(i.REC_GOOD_QTY), 0)
    FROM INVENTORY_ITEM i
    WHERE COMPANY_ID = 1
        AND i.COMPANY_BRANCH_ID = 1
        AND i.INV_ITEM_STATUS = 'Inward'
        AND i.GRN_DATE <  '2017-01-10'
    GROUP BY i.ITEM_ID
) 
, StockRequisition as
(
    SELECT ITEM_ID
        , TotalLitre = SUM(TOTAL_LITRE)
    FROM STOCK_REQUISITION_ITEM B
    JOIN STOCK_REQUISITION A ON A.ID = B.REQUISITION_ID
    WHERE A.COMPANY_ID = 1
        AND A.REQ_FROM_BRANCH_ID = 1 
        AND A.REQUISITION_DATE < '2017-01-10'
    GROUP BY B.ITEM_ID
) 
StockReturn as
(
    SELECT ITEM_ID
        , ReturnQuantity = SUM(RETURN_QUANTITY)
    FROM STOCK_RETURN_ITEM B
    JOIN STOCK_RETURN A ON A.ID = B.STOCK_RETURN_ID
    WHERE A.COMPANY_ID = 1
        AND A.COMPANY_BRANCH_ID = 1 
        AND A.RETURN_DATE <= '2017-01-10'
    GROUP BY B.ITEM_ID
)

select i.ITEM_ID
    , MyCalculation = i.GoodQty - isnull(Req.TotalLitre, 0) + isnull(sr.ReturnQuantity, 0)
from Inventory i
left join StockRequisition sr on sr.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
left join StockReturn Req on Req.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
```